# Inject my controllers without needing to place them all in the head tag - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, controllers

I have a structure to my angularjs app project as below:

[image]

I am aiming to have each component have its own controller and service to display portfolio information like images, videos, links etc.

The issue I am having is that the only way I am able to define each controller is by stacking them into my head tag in the index.html file. If I choose to create more pages, I am going to have to do this over and over again, meaning lots of calls, lots of load time etc.

Is there a way to inject each of these controllers into the app.module.js file, so this is the only file that needs to be loaded?

thanks in advance.

Comment: are you talking about the script paths you will have to include?

Comment: yes. placing my script tags into the head of my index.html file.

Answer (score 0):

You will still have to place a script-tag into your html-file for every script-file you have. For testing/learning purposes you can just put them there by hand. But when this gets to annoying for you, consider using some kind of build tool like [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) where you can inject them based on folder structure for example.

Comment: I've got gulp running, so are you suggesting that I compile the scripts into one file as I am doing with my LESS to CSS? If you could elaborate, that would be brilliant. Thank you.

Comment: something like gulp-concat?

Comment: You will probably be best of by using the plugin [gulp-inject](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inject). There you can define where to grab the scripts and where to inject them in your html-file. The documentation is pretty good, so i think you'll be fine with it

Comment: Thanks, I've tried gulp-concat and the task isn't running at all, even though the task is written correctly. I have restructured the folders into individual controller directories etc. I'll try gulp-inject.

Answer (score 0):

You can define index.js file for every folder and export this modules with gulp for bundle.js
like

```
module.exports =

  angular.module('app.component.contact', [

  ]);
```

and assume that you need sub-folders and different directives at the contact folder like:

```
---contact    
     ---list    
     ---favorites
```

then:

```
module.exports =
  angular.module('app.component.contact', [
    'angularMoment',
    require("./list"),
    require("./favorites"),

]);
```

also parent of the contact like components you can do export operation like that:

```
module.exports =
  angular.module('app.component', [
    'ui.router',
    require('./about'),
    require('./contact'),
    require('./home'),

  ]);
```

this is the simple logic of the exports from child to parent folders.